# What's the difference between 知り合い & 付き合い?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I have answered this 知り合い but in answer's sheet it was 付き合い and I don't get the difference.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, 知り合い is not possible because of とは and があります.

彼女は昔の知り合いです would have been fine. However, here, the と after 彼女 indicates that we have to choose 付き合い, that is because the verb 付き合う takes the particle と.

As for the difference between 付き合い and 知り合い, 知り合い is a mere acquaintance whereas 付き合い implies a much closer relationship.

Comment: 付き合っています and 付き合いがあります are very different, and this type of 付き合い does not indicate a close relationship.

Comment: `the と after 彼女 indicates that we have to choose 付き合い, that is because the verb 付き合う takes the particle と` <-- You can use と with 知り合い, too. eg「彼女とは知り合いです。」「彼女とは長年の知り合いだ。」 (The verb 知り合う takes the particle と, too）

Answer (score 4):

知り合い refers to *people*. It means "acquaintance" in the sense of "people who know each other". It's like "friends" but not so close as 友達.

付き合い refers to *relationship*. It means "acquaintance" in the sense of "the state of knowing each other". It's close to 交際.

> 彼女とは昔から付き合いがあります。

Literally, "With her, since a long time ago, there has been 付き合い."
→ I've had 付き合い with her for a long time.

To use 知り合い:

> 彼女とは昔から知り合いです。or
>   彼女とは昔からの知り合いです。

Literally, "With her, since a long time ago, (I've) been 知り合い."
→ She and I have been 知り合い for a long time.
(i.e. She and I have known each other for a long time.)

(彼女とは昔からの付き合いです would be fine, too.)